# Php multi-dimensional array creation

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am pulling the data in my table and creating an array with the following code.

```
$variant = [];
foreach ($value as $item) {
    $variant[] = $item->name;
}
```

But I am not getting the result as below

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: This is not meant to be offensive but why do you think your code would create a multidimensional array? you define a single array then  `$variant[]=$item->name` pushes a value into that array. you never assign a second array to your array. Based on your expected output it seems that you maybe want to push        `$item->varieties` or something like this?

Comment: I will add the value I get in the form of an array to the code below.
`combinations(array(array('S','M','L', 'XL', 'XXL'), array('Yellow','Red','Blue','White','Black','Green')))`

Comment: can you please provide var_dumps for `$variant` and `$value`?

Comment: `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "S"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "M"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "L"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "XL"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "XXL"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Yellow"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Red"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "White"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Black"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "Green"
  }
}`

Comment: If that is the output of `var_dump($variant)` then you already have the correct logic. the difference comes from the fact that you are using `var_dump($variant)` but your expected output seems to be achieved with `print_r($variant)`

Comment: Now the output is like this. When it is like this, I can't get the variants as a combination
`Array
([0] => Array
        (
            [0] => S
            [1] => M
            [2] => L
            [3] => XL
            [4] => XXL
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yellow
            [1] => Red
            [2] => Blue
            [3] => White
            [4] => Black
            [5] => Green
        )

)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241156/discussion-between-seven-seas-and-tamer).